# SSL Domain redirects to irrelevant URL?

Tags: redirect, ssl, dns, cpanel, cloudflare

I'm encountering a weird issue with SSL on my domain names, where 'http://example.com' will go to my website, the https:// equivelent will redirect to someone's eBay store... selling designer sunglasses.

It's always the same site, regardless of the domain I use SSL on.

While I'm sure most visitors to my site would prefer sunglasses over an encrypted connection to my site, I'd really like to know what could be the cause of it.

My setup is as follows:

- cPanel with a self-signed SSL certificate
- CloudFlare on the domain with Full SSL mode enabled

After a little while it seems to sort itself out, I'm not sure whether it's another site hosted on the same shared server, or if it's a CloudFlare issue - but I'm interested in any theories you may have.

Ben,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an issue with your domain handling SSL on a shared server (it is likely the site you see resides on the same server at your host). I would check with your hosting provider if you continue to see the issue.

Comment: After a reverse IP lookup on both my domain name, and the server IP address, I couldn't find the site I was being redirected to - but I reckon you're right.

I'll definitely be in touch with them if it happens again, though it only seems to occur when I'm setting up SSL on a new domain.

Answer (score 0):

Got in contact with the hosting provider, they told me it was an issue caused by their 'SNI functionality' or 'Server Name Indicator' feature that allows multiple websites to be hosted on one IP address.

After reinstalling the SSL certificates and clearing the DNS cache in my browser, the redirection was no longer occurring.